What is the possible enhancement for this mode?
I use LSTM for classifying multi-label movie genres with Word2Vec as feature extraction; the model resulted in metrics as Test Loss: 0.3067, Test Accuracy: 0.5144 as illustrated in the figure.
What is the possible improvement for this model? 
I use the bellow code:
# Tokenize text
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(merged_df['clean'])

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(merged_df['clean'])
X = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_len, padding='post', truncating='post')  # Pad sequences to max length

# Vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1  # Include 0 for padding
print(f"Vocabulary Size: {vocab_size}")

#vocab_size=37696
embedding_dim=300
max_len=1000

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_dim))

# Map words to vectors
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    if word in word2vec:
        embedding_matrix[i] = word2vec[word]
    else:
        # Initialize words not in Word2Vec with random values
        embedding_matrix[i] = np.random.uniform(-0.25, 0.25, embedding_dim)

print(f"Embedding Matrix Shape: {embedding_matrix.shape}")



from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Bidirectional, LSTM, Attention, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# Define input layer (shape = (None, max_len))
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_len,))
embedded_input = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                           output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                           weights=[embedding_matrix], 
                           input_length=max_len, 
                           trainable=False)(input_layer)
query = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(embedded_input)
attention_output = Attention()([query, query])  # Self-attention mechanism
attention_output = BatchNormalization()(attention_output)
attention_output = Dropout(0.5)(attention_output)
lstm_output = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(attention_output)
lstm_output = Dropout(0.5)(lstm_output)
lstm_output2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False))(lstm_output)
lstm_output2 = Dropout(0.5)(lstm_output2)
output_layer = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(lstm_output2)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True,mode='auto')
lr_scheduler = Red**strong text**uceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=3, verbose=1)

history =model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50, batch_size=32, callbacks=[early_stop, lr_scheduler])


Can you share sample input data, meta data like total no. of data across different label.

This is the content of ReadMe file that descript the dataset:


Script Folder: contains scrip of the movies, files are saved by IMDB ID (we got these scripts from "http://ritual.uh.edu/1493-2" and added 50 new movies to them)


Posters Folder: contains image posters of movies, images are saved by IMDB ID


metadata.csv: each row contains metadata data information of movies {IMDB_ID, Title, Genre, MPAA_rating, Actors, Poster_source, Director, year }
There are 24 genres as : 'Action' 'Adult' 'Adventure' 'Animation' 'Biography' 'Comedy' 'Crime' 'Documentary' 'Drama' 'Family' and other


